# vue js pagination with simple vuejs plugin

Tags: vue.js, pagination

I am trying to create a paginated flexbox using data from an API but struggle with it although I read the setup step-by step.

Here is my code without styles:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <paginate name="articles" :list="articles" class="paginate-list">
      <li v-for="item in paginated('articles')">
        {{ item }}
      </li>
    </paginate>
    <paginate-links for="items" :show-step-links="true"></paginate-links>
    <paginate-links for="items" :limit="2" :show-step-links="true"> 
    </paginate-links>
    <paginate-links for="items" :simple="{ next: 'Next »', prev: '« Back' }">
    </paginate-links>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script> 
  import axios from 'axios'; 
  import VuePaginate from 'vue-paginate' 

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        items:[],
        paginate: [articles]
      }
    }, 
    created() {
      axios.get(https://zbeta2.mykuwaitnet.net/backend/en/api/v2/media-center/press-release/?page_size=61&type=5) 
        .then(response => { 
          this.items = response.data 
        }) 
    } 
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: that is the script part:     
    <script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    import VuePaginate from 'vue-paginate'
    
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          items:[],
          paginate: [`articles`]
        }
      },
    
    
      created() {
        axios.get(`https://zbeta2.mykuwaitnet.net/backend/en/api/v2/media-center/press-release/?page_size=61&type=5`)
    
    
        .then(response => {
         
          this.items = response.data
        })
        
      }
    }
    
    </script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Step 1:*** Install `npm install --save vue-paginate`
***Step 2:*** Import `vue-paginate` component in `main.js`

```
import VuePaginate from "vue-paginate";
Vue.use(VuePaginate);
```

***Step 3:*** `HTML` template will be like,

```
 <template>
  <div id="app">
    <paginate ref="paginator" class="flex-container" name="items" :list="items">
      <li
        v-for="(item, index) in paginated('items')"
        :key="index"
        class="flex-item">
        <h4>{{ item.pub_date }}, {{ item.title }}</h4>
        <img :src="item.image && item.image.file" />
        <div class="downloads">
          <span
            v-for="downloadable in item.downloadable.filter(
              (d) => !!d.document_en
            )"
            :key="downloadable.id">
            <a :href="downloadable.document_en.file">Download</a>
          </span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </paginate>
    <paginate-links
      for="items"
      :limit="2"
      :show-step-links="true"></paginate-links>
  </div>
</template>
```

***Step 4:*** Your component `script` like

```
<script>
  import axios from "axios";
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        items: [],
        paginate: ["items"],
      };
    },
    created() {
      this.loadPressRelease();
    },
    methods: {
      loadPressRelease() {
        axios.get(`https://zbeta2.mykuwaitnet.net/backend/en/api/v2/media-center/press-release/?page_size=61&type=5`)
        .then((response) => {
          this.items = response.data.results;
        });
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

***Step 5:*** `CSS` style

```
<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
ul.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-direction: row wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
li img {
  display: initial;
  height: 100px;
}
.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  width: calc(100% / 3.5);
  padding: 5px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
.downloads {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
ul.paginate-links.items li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
}
ul.paginate-links.items a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
ul.paginate-links.items li.active a {
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul.paginate-links.items li.next:before {
  content: " | ";
  margin-right: 13px;
  color: #ddd;
}
ul.paginate-links.items li.disabled a {
  color: #ccc;
  cursor: no-drop;
}
</style>
```

[DEMO Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-dan-vb41s)

Comment: thanks a lot, Jebasuthan, this work but as I can see you did not use the pagination template but created a custom pagination, is that corret?

Comment: @BalazsKelemen No I used the same `pagination` component but I added when we click the page number called the `rest api`. You dont need a `rest api` call when click on next page? You have to add the pagination only for `this.items` response instead of calling api again and again?

Comment: @ Jebasuthan, I am confused, so you would not need to import it at the beginning of the script? Also, I guess I don`t need a rest API

Comment: also, possible to avoid Loader and moment?

Comment: @BalazsKelemen Okay got it. Let me update the code and demo link too

Comment: @BalazsKelemen I updated the answer and demo link too. Can you verify and let me know. I removed `Loader` and `moment`.

Comment: that is awesome! I cannot be grateful enough, now I just need to go line by line to understand :D

Comment: @BalazsKelemen Its my pleasure! Thank you.